# Test useRef's currents' properties using jest-enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, use-ref

I am trying to test a hidden file inputs click using Jest-enzyme, for the following component.

```
const UploadField = ({handleFileUpload}) => {
    const hiddenFileInputRef = React.useRef(null);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        handleFileUpload(event.target.files[0]);
    };

    const handleClick = () => {
        hiddenFileInputRef.current.click();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <input
                type="file"              
                ref={hiddenFileInputRef}
                onChange={handleChange}
                style={{display: 'none'}}
            />
            <div
                onClick={handleClick}
                className="upload-button-container">
              upload file
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

i tried the following test :

```
        it('should call handle click of hidden fileinput on click of div', () => {
            const useRefSpy = jest
                .spyOn(React, 'useRef')
                .mockReturnValueOnce({current: {click: jest.fn()}});
            let divWrapper = wrapper.find(
                '.upload-button-container'
            );
            divWrapper.simulate('click');
            expect(useRefSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
           
        });
```

It gives an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null" . what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It's typically not good form to test specific implementation details of state and `use*` hooks in jest and the react testing libraries do NOT give you a lot of good tools to do that for a reason.  You'll be better served testing a side effect (your spy) by putting it into your component the same way the real implementation would (e.g. through props)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to check if you were able find the right div by logging wrapperDiv.html() or debugging
2. I think you might have to pass the event like in this post. [Simulating a Div Click on Enzyme and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566125/simulating-a-div-click-on-enzyme-and-react)